# $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $B$ is invertible. If $A = B^{-1}CB$, show that $A^3 = B^{-1}C^3B$

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

Since $A=B^{-1}CB$,  and $B^{-1}B=I_{n \times n}$

By matrix property of associablity

$A=C(B^{-1}B)$

$A=CI_{n \times n}$

$A^3=C^3I_{n \times n}$

$A^3=C^3B^{-1}B$

Is my solution correct? If not, please guide me to the correct solution.

Comment: No, the very first line $A=CB^{-1}B$ is wrong. just do $A^3=AAA$ and replace $A$ by its expression with $C$.

Comment: @c00kie132 : Do you mean $B^{-1}B=1
$ or $B^{-1}B=I_{n \times n}$?

Comment: You need to go back and review what the associativity property is. That isn't it.

Comment: Start with something easier. Compute $A^2=(B^{-1}CB)(B^{-1}CB)$. This can't be so difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is **not** correct, because matrix multiplication is **not** commutative in general. Its easy to cook up counterexamples, e.g.
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, B=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
satisfy
$$AB = B \neq 0 = BA$$
Hence your computation $$A=B^{-1}CB = CB^{-1}B$$
fails at the second identity.

To solve the exercise write
$$\begin{align*}
A^3 &= (B^{-1}CB)^3 \\&= (B^{-1}CB)(B^{-1}CB)(B^{-1}CB)\\&= B^{-1}C(BB^{-1})C(BB^{-1})CB\\&= B^{-1}C^3B\end{align*}$$